# Axis label specifications in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I'm attempting to have a two-line y-axis label that contains a superscript in ggplot and I am struggling.

I want the y axis label to say “[3H]ASEM binding (pmol/g)” with the 3 superscripted and (pmol/g) on a separate line.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
labs(x="", y=expression(paste("[" ^3 "H] ASEM Binding \n (pmol/g)")))
```

And it's given me the error "unexpected string constant"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an empty ''(2 single quotes) prior to the ^3.

```
  ggplot(sample_data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(
    x = "",
    y = expression(atop(paste("[", ''^3, "H] ASEM Binding"), "(pmol/g)"))
  )
```

[image]

Another alternative is:

```
y = expression(atop("["^3*"H] ASEM Binding", "(pmol/g)"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're doing with your for loop, but this code chunk should get you the two-lined axis label with a superscript for which you are looking.

```
library(tidyverse)

sample_data <- tibble(x = rnorm(1000),
       y = x^2)

sample_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(
    x = "X",
    y = expression(atop("Variable", X^2))
  )
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I need. I adjusted my question above to hopefully make it a bit clearer. I need the super script to come after the first [ and before the H in the first line of the label.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point()+
  labs(x = "",
       y = expression(atop("[ "^3*H~"] ASEM Binding", "(pmol/g)")))+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(10, 10, 20, 10), "mm"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>